# Prevent Slide down on to perform some other action on mouse-wheel scroll in Fullpage js

Tags: fullpage.js, slidedown, slideup

I am using fullpage js in a website and i need to stop a particular slide to scroll down on mouse wheel scroll. Rest slides will slide normally. On 4th slide(slide in my case), i have two images which i want to display on scroll one by one. First image will be visible by default and on scroll 2nd image will display and first will be hidden. During this, slide will not scroll down. Once 2nd image is displayed then slide will scroll down to next slide. and reverse function will be performed on 4th slide while scrolling up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Fullpage</title>
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.8.8/jquery.fullPage.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
        #fullpage img{width: 100%;}
        #fullpage .section{overflow: hidden;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="fullpage">
            <section class="section slide1">
                <div class="image"><img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/750/arch" alt=""></div>
            </section>
            <section class="section slide2">
                <div class="image"><img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/750/tech/sepia" alt=""></div>
            </section>
            <section class="section slide3">
                <div class="image"><img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/750/tech" alt=""></div>
            </section>
            <section class="section slide4">
                <div class="image image1"><img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/750/natureg" alt=""></div>
                <div class="image image2"><img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/750/people" alt=""></div>
            </section>
            <section class="section slide5">
                <div class="image"><img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/750/animals" alt=""></div>
            </section>
            <section class="section slide6">
                <div class="image"><img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/750/tech/grayscale" alt=""></div>
            </section>
        </div>


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.8.8/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.8.8/vendors/scrolloverflow.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('#fullpage').fullpage({
                verticalCentered: true,
                navigation: true,
                navigationPosition: 'right',
                scrollingSpeed: 800,
                scrollBar: true,
                responsiveWidth: 1024,
                afterResponsive: function(isResponsive){}
            });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read [how to cancel a movement before it takes place](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#cancelling-the-scroll-before-it-takes-place).

Comment: Thanks, it could stop the scroll but i need to resume scrolling effect after that.

Comment: Then use `moveSectionDown` or Up after whatever you have to do.